# How to use multiple select count of different col and have aggregated results in postgress?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I'm trying to make the following call:

```
select count(col_a) as aa from sm.sensor_sync;
select count(col_b) as bb from sm.sensor_sync;
------?
```

each of the selects work independently, how to i perform them together and have a results of 2 col with the relevant counts?

I would like to the results as 1 row with 2 col aa,bb

something like:

```
| aa | bb |
  10   1
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: question has been updated

Comment: `select count(col_a), count(col_b) from ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments, just use two aggregate functions to get this data.

```
SELECT 
    count(col_a) as aa,
    count(col_b) as bb 
FROM sm.sensor_sync;
```